# Setting client-side timeout per request with Alamofire [swift]?

Tags: swift, timeout, client, nsurlrequest, alamofire

I'm trying to set a client-side timeout per request for Alamofire for Swift. The lead architect told me to set this on NSURLRequest, but I'm completely confused on how to actually do that in practice.

Can someone who has done this give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I think this code may works.

```
var alamofireManager : Alamofire.Manager?

func some(){
  let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
  configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 2 // seconds

  self.alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
  self.alamofireManager!.request(.GET, "http://example.com/")
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in

    }
}
```

Comment: Why configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource and not configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest ?

Comment: Setting timeoutIntervalForRequest solved my timeout problem. Prior to that, long requests to an API were timing out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use a per-request timeout using `URLRequest`:

```
Alamofire.request(URLRequest(url: ..., cachePolicy: ..., timeoutInterval: 10))
    .response(...)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.